# Try to open my Excel file using C# and get an error

Tags: c#, excel

I try to read my Exel file from code and received `System.InvalidCastException`:

`Additional information: Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Worksheet'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{297DC8D9-EABD-45A1-BDEF-68AB67E5C3C3}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).`

This error occurs in `objsheet = appExcel.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet;` so I try to cast it into `objsheet = (Worksheet)appExcel.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet;` but this error still exist

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

private static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application appExcel;
private static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook newWorkbook = null;
private static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet objsheet = null;
private static string file = @"D:\file.xlsx";

      //Method to initialize opening Excel
    static void excel_init(String path)
    {
        //appExcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
        {
            // then go and load this into excel
            newWorkbook = appExcel.Workbooks.Open(file, true, true);

            int count = newWorkbook.Worksheets.Count;
            if (count > 0)
            {
                objsheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)newWorkbook.Worksheets[1];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to open file!");
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(appExcel);
            appExcel = null;
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
        }
    }
```

newWorkbook is null.

Comment: You are checking if 'path' exists and then opening a workbook from 'file'.  Is that correct?

Comment: Are you sure a sheet is active? The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._workbook.activesheet(v=office.15).aspx) says that this property can return Nothing if no sheet is active.

Comment: Does the machine you're running this on actually have the correct version of Excel installed?

Comment: What do you mean the correct version ? the file exist and all i want to do is add the option to add my excel file from code

Comment: You are going to have so many memory leaks and open coms with this code. Please, read more into working with COM objects. You may want to start with a google search for two dot rule.

Comment: I don't understand why you have a **path** parameter but then you attempt to open the file found at the **file** field. Is this intentional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code and see if it works, if not let us know what problems you have:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace Excel_Sample
{
    public partial class YourClass
    {
        Excel.Application appExcel;
        Excel.Workbook newWorkbook;
        Excel.Worksheet objsheet;
        string file = @"D:\file.xlsx";

        static void excel_init()
        {
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(file))
            {
                //Start Excel and get Application object.
                appExcel = new Excel.Application();
                //Get a workbook.;
                newWorkbook = (Excel.Workbook)(appExcel.Workbooks.Open(file));

                int count = newWorkbook.Worksheets.Count;
                if (count > 0)
                {
                    //Get Your Worksheet
                    objsheet = (Excel.Worksheet)newWorkbook.ActiveSheet;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to open file!");
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(appExcel);
                appExcel = null;
                System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cannot open the excel file, returns ``The server threw an exception. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT)) ``

Answer (score 1):

Workbook.ActiveSheet Property might not be the best choice for programmatically opened Excel files as it can actually return a [non-Worksheet object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._workbook.activesheet%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

You might want to consider checking sheets count and using indexes:

```
int count = newWorkbook.Worksheets.Count;
if (count > 0)
{
    objsheet = (Worksheet) newWorkbook.Worksheets[1];
}
```

And try not to break the [2-dot rule](http://www.breezetree.com/blog/index.php/common-mistakes-programming-excel-with-c-sharp/) - you'll need to release all you COM's to properly close your app and Excel.

**Edited**:

You could be mixing Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel with Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel namespaces.

Try to declare and assign as follows:

```
private static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet objsheet = null;
...
objsheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet) newWorkbook.Worksheets[1];
```

Comment: It seems that there are no worksheets in your book. Can you open the file manually and see if there is anything inside?

And **count** is actually greater than 0?

Comment: What do you mean there is no worksheets ? in my file i have 4 seets

Comment: Edited my answer - please check.

Comment: See my update, Object reference not set to an instance of an object because newWorkbook is null

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are using

```
    Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Worksheet
```

instead of

```
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
```

which is why you are getting an invalid cast exception.